# Android Travis CI Error: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/android-sdk

Tags: android, testing, travis-ci

I am trying to learn how to use Travis CI in Android , but when I push my code to the Github, Travis CI gives me an error : **`failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/android-sdk`**,

my ***.travis.yml*** file is :

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-23.0.0
    - android-L
    - sys-img-x86-android-tv-l
    - add-on
    - extra
script: ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

And my ***build.gradle*** file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xhome.uestcfei.com.loadingpoppointdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile project(':loadingpoppoint')
}
```

I am new to Travis CI ,I search for solutions by Google ,there are solutions for this error ,but worked only for local compilation rather than Travis CI . Is anybody can help me out?

**Really Thanks a lot !**

Answer (score 3):

Try to add next line in `components:` section in your `.travis.yml`:

```
- android-23
```

So, full `.travis.yml` will be:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-23.0.0
    - android-23
    - android-L
    - sys-img-x86-android-tv-l
    - add-on
    - extra
script: ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

For more information see [Building an Android Project (beta)](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android)

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works ! For I can't find android-23 in that office blog , I think android-23 not supported ,actually I am wrong .Thanks again !